# Linux Alternative for Windows RDP

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I am searching for a Linux alternative, which has the following specific features:

- When I remotely login to my workstation from my portable device, my workstation should show a lockscreen, and my portable device should show my current desktop. This feature is crucial for my use case.
- All, or almost all, keyboard shortcuts (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, etc.) should be executed on the remote desktop, and not on the portable device's desktop.

The current software I have tried out, and the issues I have faced with them:

- Chrome Remote Desktop: Logs in to a parallel session. Does not forward almost any keystrokes.
- TeamViewer: Does not lock the remote screen. The "black screen" and "block remote input" options are greyed out as these features do not work on Linux devices in the TeamViewer software.
- Multiple VNC apps (TigerVNC, RealVNC, UltraVNC): They are not able to lock my workstation's screen.

Please do let me know of your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just lock your screen when you leave your workstation? then VPN will work just fine

Comment: Can you please explain on how a VPN will help in showing what's on the workstation's screen? I'd need to run a screen mirroring software like an RDP or VNC of sorts, right?

Comment: sorry I meant VNC, not VPN

Comment: Leaving your workstation without locking it is always a bad behavior on security point of view, so don't expect the VNC to be secure that way

Comment: I always found that NX was the most capable replacement for RDP, but YMMV.

Comment: Clarification, please... is the remote computer running Linux, or the portable device, or both? If one is not, what is it running?

Comment: @jeff-zeitlin Both are running gLinux, which is a Google-specific Debian distro

Comment: @phuclv If I use VNC, I am in exactly the problem that I am looking forward to avoid; i.e., keeping the workstation unlocked, because VNC is literally a screen mirroring and remote input control protocol. What I've looking for is an exact feature set provided by the Windows RDP software. Which is that it only allows one individual at a time to login to a Windows user (either local or remote). Thus, if I login remotely to my same Linux user ID, my workstation will always be locked.

Comment: @phuclv - VNC is not suitable for the querent's needs as defined; in order to actually use the remote computer, it will need to be unlocked. RDP, except on a computer configured with a Windows Server OS as a Terminal Server, only allows one user to be logged on at a time - if a user is logged in via RDP, the "console" will show a "lock screen" and not allow another user to log in at the console.

Comment: I will not offer this as an Answer, because I don't know whether these will serve your needs (I am, of necessity, a Windows guy, not a Linux guy), but a bingleduck (**Bing** / Goo**gle** / **Duck**duckgo) on "rdp for linux" turned up [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/), [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), and [Remmina](https://www.remmina.org/wp/).

Comment: @phuclv - With VNC, when I log in from a remote computer, the local computer is unlocked, and what I am doing most certainly is visible to anyone who happens to be standing by the remote computer - and the remote keyboard is also unlocked, allowing someone standing there to actually interfere with what I am doing from the remote. The querent specifically said this in his earlier comment (14 hours ago as I write this).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin maybe I'm wrong but the last time I used VNC years ago I don't think it showed my desktop. But even then the OP can find many solutions with a simple Google search: [Disable local screen when remote VNC client connects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111418/44425), [Unlocking the display of a VNC session while leaving the physical display locked](https://superuser.com/q/189802/241386), [VNC session with locked screen](https://superuser.com/q/407407/241386), [How to decouple the VNC server's screen from the physical screen?](https://superuser.com/q/191312/241386)

Comment: [How can I leave the remote screen locked when I ARD/VNC/etc. to my Mac?](https://superuser.com/q/51529/241386)

Comment: @phuclv - None of the links actually meet the querent's stated needs - and, in fact, RDP on Windows wouldn't, either, as it appears that the querent wishes to "capture" the session that he walked away from on the console. The closest I've seen to what the querent wants is actually [Dameware](https://dameware.com), which does permit the remote user to lock out the console's mouse/keyboard, but it doesn't do anything about the screen, and may require that the accessing computer be running Windows (though the remote controlled computer can now apparently be Mac/Linux as well).

Comment: If your remote workstation is Linux, then why not just tunnel X over SSH?

Comment: I think that would cause the remote workstation's screen to be viewed on my client? Then that entails the remote machine be unlocked when I'm remotely using it.